# How should I interprent the singular value decomposition(SVD)?

Tags: svd, data-analysis

Let's say that I have this data matrix, which describe measurements of temperature over 10 different weather stations:

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
-5 & -5 &  -6&  -10&  -20&  -3&  -20&  -25&  -30& 6\\ 
-4 & -6 &  -6&  -9&  -10&  -2&  -15&  -20&  -25& 6\\ 
-3 & -3 &  -6&  -10&  -11&  1&  -10&  -15&  -22& 4\\ 
-4 & -3 &  -4&  -4&  -12&  2&  -5&  -10&  -20& 7\\ 
-3 & -4 &  -2&  -1&  -10&  5&  0&  -5&  -18& 9\\ 
1 &  -1&  1&  4&  -4&  6&  2&  1&  -15& 10\\ 
0 &  0&  0&  5&  -4&  7&  5&  5&  -14& 15\\ 
2 &  1&  1&  6&  -2&  5&  10&  7&  -13& 20\\ 
3 &  2&  2&  7&  -1&  4&  15&  10&  -12& 30\\ 
5 &  1&  3&  8&  0&  3&  20&  15&  -5& 31
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where each column is measurement each day and each row is the weather station.

CODE:

```
H = [
-5  -5   -6  -10 -20  -3  -20  -25  -30 6; 
-4  -6   -6  -9  -10  -2  -15  -20  -25 6; 
-3  -3   -6  -10  -11  1  -10  -15  -22 4; 
-4  -3   -4  -4  -12  2  -5  -10  -20 7; 
-3  -4   -2  -1  -10  5  0  -5  -18 9;
1   -1  1  4  -4  6 2  1 -15 10; 
0   0  0  5  -4  7  5 5  -14 15; 
2   1  1  6  -2  5  10  7  -13 20;
3   2  2  7  -1  4  15  10  -12 30; 
5   1  3  8  0  3  20  15  -5 31]

[U, E, V] = svd(H)
```

But what would $U$, $E$ and $V$ mean? Well, I know that $E$ is just scalars. But I don't know what kind if scalars they are. Are they scalars of temperature? Scalars of vectors in some weird spaces?

Can some one explain what $U$, $E$ and $V$ mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular value decomposition is relevant when you see your matrix as a linear operator. If you just have rows of data, it is hard to imagine that the singular value decomposition will tell you anything about your data.

Comment: So if my data is nonlinear. What should I use then? Let's assume that my data is linear in this case. What would I see?